# How to pass an array to a C# method?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have my main program which contains an array called `setOfBalls[i]` which stores ellipses. The ellipses have three properties:

```
setOfBalls[i].velocity;
setOfBalls[i].direction;
setOfBalls[i].mass;
```

Then I have a collision class and need to be able to access the arrays with direction, velocity and mass in the collision class called `Collisions.cs`.
I need to be able to detect a two body collision out of my three balls but I do not know how to get the array from main program to my collision class?

```
 public Boolean twoBodyCollision()
 {
 }
```

Comment: How are you calling `twoBodyCollision()`?

Comment: As an aside, unless you have some particular reason not to, it's recommended to follow .NET naming conventions, according to which public methods and fields should begin with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding parameters to your method and send the array as an argument; e.g.

`public boolean HasCollidingObjects(Ball[] listOfBalls) { // ... }`

Here I assume you're using a `Ball` class, but it's only an example. Use your class instead.

Also, you should use C# naming conventions instead of Java's. You can check the MSDN pages for information on what these are.

Answer (score 0):

To pass an object into a class, you can use a constructor:

```
private string[] setofBalls;
public ClassName(string[] setBalls) 
{
    setofBalls = setBalls;
}

public void DoSomething() 
{
    foreach (string ball in setofBalls) { ...... }
}
```

More on Object Oriented Programming with C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of the class you have your method in then call if from your "main program"

```
 public void MethodInMainProgram()
    {
        Collision collision = new Collision();
        collision.TwoBodyCollision(setOfBalls);
    }

public class Collision
{      

    public void TwoBodyCollision(Ellipse[] ellipses)
    {
        //logic that detects collisions
    }
}
```

more info on creating instances [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/new)